# Notepad++ RegEx delete line starting with \pard.....ending with line feed

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace, linefeed

I'm cleaning up files using Notepad ++, and trying to delete lines that start with `\pard` and have some text then end with a line feed. But `\n` doesn't work in RegEx and `.*` doesn't work in an extended find and replace.

This is what I've tried unsuccessfully: `\pard.*\n`

`\pard.*` works but leaves the line feed in RegEx.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918158/how-to-delete-specific-lines-on-notepad/918225#918225) to a closely related question will do what you need.

Comment: Yeah, I think Cameron's suggestion is the best you're going to do--with Notepad++, at least.  I recommend you get an editor with *real* regex support, like EditPad Pro.  http://www.editpadpro.com/

Comment: To anyone of the future: You could also try https://stackoverflow.com/a/918225 and put off learning regex for some more time (but it will inevitably have to happen some day, I trust).

Answer (score 2):

```
\\pard.*(\r)?\n
```

The question mark after the repeater is so that it isn't greedy or it will swallow most of the file including the parts it shouldn't...

Editted: Now it should handle line breaks properly

**Edit:** Try this

```
^\\pard.*$
```

Comment: Notepad++ does not recognize greedy/ungreedy modifiers.

Comment: The problem isn't the carriage return, it's Notepad++ itself.  NPP's "Regular Expression" search mode works on one line at a time--it actually strips off the line separators before applying the regex.  And its "Extended" mode supports several kinds of escapes including `\n`, `\r`, etc., but has none of the other features associated with regexes (or even globs).  There's no way to combine the two modes; as the OP said, you can have line separators or regexes, but not both.

Comment: No I know theres a way, I used to use it all the time (Before I switched to linux)

Try the new one...

Comment: Nope!  `^\\pard.*$` works in NPP like like it does in any other flavor: it finds the correct line, but the match doesn't include the line separators (leading *or* trailing).  Maybe you're thinking of the "Find All/Delete Bookmarked Lines" trick from that other thread Cameron linked to.  Or a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for all the interest, unfortunately I had to complete the task somewhat manually and no longer have the files to trial your suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps replace would work if you used "select all" first, either way, npp seems to be a pita, I'd just open it in something more robust.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean exactly "\pard" or  "\p"ard?  If it's the first then you need to escape the "\" with another "\".

```
\\pard.*\n
```

You may also need to look at the new line character actually being a pc format which is \r\n

```
\\pard.*\r\n
```