# Select text by some property in notepad++?

Tags: select, text, notepad++

I have a file with many topics and lecture structure.
Sometimes I add little notes of things I want to talk about on each subject.

I would like at some point to select all the notes and delete them.

I noticed Notepad++ as style tokens. So I can add them to my notes. But how do I select all the text using a specific style?

Is there a another way to mark text in notepad to later select it automatically?

Cheers

Comment: Could you give us a sample of the file you are working with? Then explain what sections you would like to delete.

Comment: Well think of a general case. Say I would want to do the same for print statements that are only for test purposes, not just for actual print outputs I want the code to generate after I'm finished.  

But taking the example of what I'm doing right now, it would be along the lines of taking out the 2nd level indented text, for example.  

http://prntscr.com/4nptwl  
I tryed to type that here in the comment but the format got lost. I know there's markups here, but it's a bit troublesome for a newbie. Comments here are a bit crap :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748313/is-there-a-way-to-delete-all-comments-in-a-file-using-notepad
This one does it for commented code.

Answer (score 0):

If each topic is fully contained on one line then the "Mark" tab in the "Find" (search) panel plus menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Copy/Cut/Remove bookmarked lines** should work. Remember to tick "Bookmark line" before clicking on "Mark all".