# Remove //<text> with a regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to quickly remove comments from code using NotePad++ regex search function and I have got a regex for several types of comment.

```
(?s)/\*.*?\*/

Removes comments like /*** comment ***/ or 
/*
 * comment
 */
```

However when it comes to a comment such as

```
your code //Comment
```

I cannot find a regex which works.

I have tried a regex such as

```
//(?:[^\w]*\w){0,}(?!\n)
```

However it doesn't stop at the end of a line.

So my question is what regex should I use which will remove from and including `//` to the end of a line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to delete all comments in a file using Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748313/is-there-a-way-to-delete-all-comments-in-a-file-using-notepad)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//.*$
```

- `//` - the comment
- `.*` - any amount of characters
- `$` - the end of the line

You have to be careful though. For example if there is a string containing `//`, it will still be considered a comment.