# Notepad++ regex -> newLine

Tags: regex, notepad++

I use Notepad++ and I need to delete all lines starting with, say "abc".

Attention, I don't need to replace the line starting with "abc" with a empty line, but I need to completely delete these lines.

How do I proceed (using regex, I suppose)?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918158/how-to-delete-specific-lines-on-notepad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try replace

```
^abc.*(\r?\n)?
```

with

```
nothing
```

The `^` indicates the start of a line.

The `.` means wild-card.

The `.*` means zero or more wild-cards.

`x?` means `x` is optional.

The `\r?\n` covers both `\r\n` (generally Windows) and `\n` (generally Unix), but must be optional to cover the last line.

Comment: Yes. And << (^|\r?\n)abc.*\r?\n >> for "abc...<something else>"

Comment: Does not work for last line of the file, when the file has no new line at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Search for this regular expression

```
^abc.*\r\n
```

Replace with nothing.

Comment: Does not work for last line of the file, when the file has no new line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex `\nabc.*` in "Find and Replace" --> "Replace"
Leave "Replace With" field empty.

EDIT : This won't work with first like (because '\n' means "new line")

Answer (score 0):

Searching a little bit more on regex in Notepad++ I discovered that the new line character is not `\n` as I expected (Windows), but the `\n\r`.

So, my regex replace expression should be:
**Find:** `abc.*\r\n`
**Replace with:** (nothing, empty field)

Comment: This would match lines with abc in the middle also.

Answer (score 0):

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the `Replace` window. Put

```
^abc.*(\r?\n)?
```

in the `Find what` and leave `Replace with` empty. Select `Reqular expression` and hit `Replace All`.

This reqular expression handles all the edge cases:

- When the first line of the file starts with `abc`
- When the last line of the file starts with `abc` and there is no new line at the end of the file.