# Regex - remove similar strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have these lines

```
http://dawn-ofthe-dead.blogspot.com/2008/02/amenra-hitch.html
http://dawn-ofthe-dead.blogspot.com/2008/0...enra-hitch.html
https://yadi.sk/mail/?hash=R041opeqcsTT3kmODt3qXcIAmcxOx1P78E1PqDOqJR8%3D
https://yadi.sk/mail/?hash=R041opeqcsTT3kmO...78E1PqDOqJR8%3D
https://mail.yandex.ru/message_part/2011%20-%20Amenra%20%26%20Oathbreaker%20(Split).rar?name=2011%20-%20Amenra%20%26%20Oathbreaker%20(Split).rar&amp;hid=1.3&amp;ids=2440000004701735584
https://mail.yandex.ru/message_part/2011%20..000004701735584
http://mediaboom.org/mp3/127749-amenra-mass-i-prayer-i-vi-2003.html
http://mediaboom.org/mp3/127749-amenra-mas....-i-vi-2003.html
```

I want remove strings with

```
..
...
....
```

because are similar almost duplicate strings.

I want this output

```
http://dawn-ofthe-dead.blogspot.com/2008/02/amenra-hitch.html
https://yadi.sk/mail/?hash=R041opeqcsTT3kmODt3qXcIAmcxOx1P78E1PqDOqJR8%3D
https://mail.yandex.ru/message_part/2011%20-%20Amenra%20%26%20Oathbreaker%20(Split).rar?name=2011%20-%20Amenra%20%26%20Oathbreaker%20(Split).rar&amp;hid=1.3&amp;ids=2440000004701735584
http://mediaboom.org/mp3/127749-amenra-mass-i-prayer-i-vi-2003.html
```

How regex? (I'm using Notepad++)

Comment: You can try like this: Search for [`.*\.\..*\n?`](https://regex101.com/r/hW0aZ1/1) and replace by empty.

Comment: Are the lines that you want to remove always follwoing the one without the dot? Would a check for 25 (or whatever number) equal characters at the start be suffivient? See [Regex101-Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX2yP4/1)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @SebastianProske seems don't work `^(.{25,})(.*)$\n\1.*` I copy on notepad++ and select regular expression but it tell me **no matches**

Comment: @SuperSonic yep, better use `^(.{25,})(.*)$\R\1.*` for the search pattern (and still `$1$2` for replace) - does this work for you?

Comment: @SebastianProske Ok now it works - please write your answer so I can assign like solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete specific lines on Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918158/how-to-delete-specific-lines-on-notepad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the condition, that the line you want to remove always follows the line without the dots, you can use the following (make sure *regular expression* is checked in Notepad++ replace dialog):

Search pattern: `^(.{25,})(.*)$\R\1.*`

Replace pattern: `$1$2`

This is checking for 25 characters in one line, that are repeated in the next line - and removes this second line. Of course you can replace 25 by whatever number you feel appropriate to avoid false positives.

Answer (score 4):

To remove all lines that have 2 or more dots, I'll do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*\.\.+.*\R?`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: I think you can drop the `+`. Further this [won't strip the last line](https://regex101.com/r/cO6nG7/1) (if there is no `\n`).

Comment: @bobblebubble: Good catch, I've made the line break optional.