# How do I mass delete lines out of Notepad++ except for ones with specific characters?

Tags: notepad++

is there also a way to delete every line that doesn't have a specific character in it? For example delete every line that doesn't include the character `@`:

```
1234 (delete)
5678 (delete)
@901 (keep)
2345 (delete)
12@5 (keep)
6789 (delete)
```

I think you get the idea, would be very helpful if someone could tell me :)

Comment: You have the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete specific lines on Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918158/how-to-delete-specific-lines-on-notepad) . Note that there are several other useful commands on the **Search** => **Bookmark** menu including **Remove unmarked lines**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex: Remove lines containing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876296/regex-remove-lines-containing)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regular expressions to mass delete such strings.

1) `Ctrl+H` for find and replace

2) in the find tab, enter the regex `[^@][0-9][^@]\w+`

3) in the replace tab just give spaces

4) click replace all

Note:- you have to select regular expression search mode while doing this. Please find image below,
[image]

Comment: This will not delete the lines. Why not simply use `^\w+\R` or, better, `^[^@]+\R`

Comment: @Toto can u explain me with that regex please?