# Removing lines with diferent specific terminations on notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file with diferent lines.

A few of the lines terminate in values such as `000`, `001`, `002`, other have different terminations, aaa, bbb etc..

The problem is, I have nearly 100 different ending values, in a thousand of lines text.

So I'm looking for a way to make this easier, as an example.

```
aldskjflaskdjh-000
alskdjfhlakjsd-001
alskdjfhlakjsd-002
alskdjfhlakjsd-003
alskdjfhlakjsd-aaa
alskdjfhlakjsd-bbb
alskdjfhlakjsd-ccc
```

I want it to delete all the files that end in a group of 3 numbers, so I'd only be left with

```
alskdjfhlakjsd-aaa
alskdjfhlakjsd-bbb
alskdjfhlakjsd-ccc
```

I've tried sublime 2, searching for -000, choose all, select the lines and press "del". But having nearly -100 in some cases turns out very hard to clean it up.

Does anyone knows a easier solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918158/how-to-delete-specific-lines-on-notepad?rq=1)

Comment: You could click alt + mark all the lines with you mouse. Then you can delete / change the entries. This will only work if the length of all the rows are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?-\d{3}(?:\R|$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  .+?       : 1 or more any character, not greedy
  -         : a dash
  \d{3}     : 3 digits
  (?:       : start non capture group
    \R      : any kind of linebreak
   |        : OR
    $       : end of line
  )         : end group
```

- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Result for given example:**

```
alskdjfhlakjsd-aaa
alskdjfhlakjsd-bbb
alskdjfhlakjsd-ccc
```

Comment: what if instead of 3 digits, i have 1 character and 2 digits, like a00 and a01?

Comment: @anotherJ.Doe: Just replace `\d{3}` with `[a-z]\d\d`